# Nancy return view as either a rendered view or unrendered file

Tags: nancy

I'm trying to do something slightly unusual in allowing for a file to be returned by Nancy as both a rendered view and as an unrendered file if requested.  My code is similar to:

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule() : base("/apath")
    {
        Get["/{Name}"] = parameters =>
             {
                 return View[parameters.Name];
             };

        Get["/{Name}/AsFile"] = parameters =>
            {
                return Response.AsFile(parameters.Name);
            };
    }
}
```

My files are stored relative to the application root in `/Views/apath`

Nancy works perfectly when returning the file as a View, but returns a NotFound http status code when trying to serve it as a file.

I've been trying to change the path passed to Response.AsFile, but no luck as yet.

How can I get the AsFile route working?

Comment: I'm able to get the file if I use the following, `@".\Views\apath\"+ (string)parameters.Name + ".extension"`. But I'd like to be able to do what Views[] does, and avoid needing to add the extension.

Comment: I've also explored hooking up `StaticContentsConventions` in a Bootstrapper, but as I'm capturing the request via an explicit route it doesn't seem applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Nancy does not support this out of the box, with good reason.

The thing that is super scary about what you're trying to achieve is, if I passed in a url like:

`..%2Fweb.config`

I could return the config file back, get access to your connection strings, and basically hack your website.

What you want to do is have some sort of look up table in a database, or a flat file or something that allows you to correlate a name to a physical file.

<kbd>Name</kbd>          <kbd>Path</kbd>                                  
<kbd>my-cat</kbd>        <kbd>../pictures/cat/my-cat.jpg</kbd> 
<kbd>my-dog</kbd>       <kbd>../pictures/cat/my-dog.jpg</kbd>

Then you can look up the name, return the filename, and then use that in your existing code:

```
Get["/{Name}/AsFile"] = parameters =>
{
  var file = myFileService.GetFile(parameters.Name);

  return Response.AsFile(file.Path);
};
```

Also if the file doesn't exist, then you know it might be an unsafe request and can tell the user to get lost!

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm running a self hosted Nancy on localhost, so the client can be considered to have full access to the files anyway.